# Maximize this parametric function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question:

For what values of $a>0$ is $$\frac1{1+\vert x\vert}+\frac1{1+\vert x-a\vert}$$ 
is maximized?

I have no idea on how to work with derivatives of absolute values. Any help is appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx}|f(x)|=\dfrac{|f(x)|}{f(x)}\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)$

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense to me.  Do you mean "for what value of $x$ is the expression maximized, given $a>0?"

Comment: I suspect the question should be "For what values of $x>0$" And unless $a>0$ the answer will be: None.

Comment: @saulspatz actually I found this exercise on Spivak’s calculus and it is worded like this. So you should email him and ask him about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 
$$f(x)=\frac1{1+\vert x\vert}+\frac1{1+\vert x-a\vert}$$
And split it in the following way
 $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{1-x+a}   &\text{if $x<0$}\\
\frac1{1+x}+\frac1{1-x+a}  &\text{if $0\leq x<a$}\\
\frac1{1+x}+\frac1{1+x-a}  &\text{if $x\geq a$}.                 
\end{cases}$$
and calculating the first derivative you obtain
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(a-x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}   &\text{if $x<0$}\\
\frac{1}{(a-x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}  &\text{if $0< x<a$}\\
-\frac{1}{(-a+x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}  &\text{if $x> a$}.                 
\end{cases}$$
You can immediately notice that $f(x)$ is increasing for  $x<0$ since
$$\left\{\frac{1}{(a-x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}>0\,\Big{|}\,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$
Also,
$$\frac{1}{(a-x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{-a^2+2 a x-2 a+4 x}{(x+1)^2 (a-x+1)^2}$$
which is negative for $x<a/2$, therefore the function $f(x)$ is decreasing in $\left(0,\frac{a}{2}\right)$. This implies that $x=0$ is a maximum. Also, being that $f(x)$ is symmetric with respect to $x=a/2$, there is another maximum point, with the same value of the one found previously, at $x=a$.The function at these critical points has value:
$$f(0)=f(a)=\frac{2+a}{1+a}.$$

Comment: thanks for the reply